# Работа со списком экземпляров класса по определенным атрибутам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пусть есть класс `People`, объекты которого будут иметь 7 атрибутов:

```py
people=list()

class People:

   def ___init___ (self,c,d,g,h,s,u,y):

      self.c=c
      self.d=d
      self.g=g
      self.h=h
      self.s=s
      self.u=u
      self.y=y
```

Создаю список одинаковых объектов одного типа:

```py
for i in range(40):

     obj=People (0,1,1,1,1,1,1)

     people.append(obj)
```

и другого типа:

```py
 for j in range(30):

     obj = People (0,0,0,1,1,0,1)
     people.append(obj)
```

Теперь мне нужно сделать цикл `for`, в котором нужно перебрать все элементы списка, и если у них аргумент `с=0`, то записать количество таких элементов в переменную `w`.

Answer (score 3):

У вас в коде некоторое кол-во ошибок, например у init должно быть два подчеркивания, и создание объекта должно делаться иначе - я привел два варианта

```
people=list()

class People:
   def __init__ (self,c,d,g,h,s,u,y):
      self.c=c
      self.d=d
      self.g=g
      self.h=h
      self.s=s
      self.u=u
      self.y=y

for i in range(40):
     a = People(0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
     people.append(a)

for j in range(30):
     people.append(People(0,0,0,1,1,0,1))

print(sum(o.c == 0 for o in people))
# 70
```